# How to get user information on app installation

Tags: ios

Is there a way (if possible) to fetch some user info, such as users language or app version (to store in server), on app installation, before the app is launched or maybe on app launch but only once.
I looked into NSUserDefaults but i don't think it will exactly serve what i want.
I can get the user info i need in the app delegate - didFinishLaunchingWithOptions, but i want the info stored only once at app installation (time & date) and not every time user will launch the app.
couldn't find info on google or SO that will help accomplishing exactly what i want...

any help will be very much appreciated.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many open source projects doing exactly this. Just take a look at one of these projects to get an impression on how to access this information. Just as an example: [Countly](https://github.com/Countly/countly-sdk-ios/blob/master/Countly.m)

If you want to access this information only once, just set a `BOOL` in `NSUserDefaults` that indicates whether or not you already got it.

Comment: thanks for the quick response, i'll take a look at the example and try your suggestion with the bool in nsuserdefaults

Comment: i've marked your answer as correct since it accomplished what i wanted (bool in user default), many thanks. but i was just wandering, in general, is there a way to get user info at the time of the installation? it can be done only through "first launch"?

Comment: No, this is not possible (as of Nov 2013). The preferred way of detecting a first launch is to make use of NSUserDefaults.